# What Encoding scheme to use for Arabic cursive text forms in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, encoding, arabic

I want to read an Arabic.txt file into MATLAB and access the unicode for each character. The issue is that matlab shows unicode for isolated character, even if the character has been written in one of the forms (initial/middle/end). I am using UTF-8 encoding scheme. For accessing file I am using fopen and textscan command. For unicode I use this function. 
dec2hex(double(char(1))).
For example for letter 'peh' initial form I am getting "067E" instead of "FB58".
Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you share some full code example for those who do not have easy access (or knowledge) of Arabic?  We can not help because we can not reproduce "peh", as we do not know how it looks like (is it what wikipedia refers as "Pe"?) nor we can write it if we would know!

Comment: Thanks for your response Ander. I actually figured it out later on.

Comment: Please do post the solution of this!

Comment: MATLAB seems to retain only isolated unicode for each character, for example for letter 'peh' I will always be getting 067E regardless of its position in the PAW  start, middle or end. One way to access and know its position is to find its neighbouring characters. If no character to its right--> start position. If characters to its left and right exist --> middle position, if blankspace or punctuation to its right-->end position. If nothing to right or left--> isolated form. These condition holds true for joiner Arabic characters. The Unicodes can be associated then for each of these forms.